# Is C++ completely object oriented language?

Tags: c++, oop

I read about small talk being completely object oriented.. is C++ also completely object oriented? if no.. then why so??

Comment: `small talk being completely object oriented`, where did you read this from? Just curious.

Comment: What does it mean "completely"?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

No, it isn't.  You can write a valid, well-coded, excellently-styled C++ program without using an object even once.

C++ supports object-oriented programming, but OO is not intrinsic to the language.  In fact, the main function isn't a member of an object.

In smalltalk or Java, you can't tie your shoes (or write "Hello, world") without at least one class.

(Of course, one can argue about Java being a completely object-oriented language too, because its primitives (say, int) are not objects.)

Comment: It even has utilities that makes it a generic programming language
eg Templates. But I have seen many school-level text books which associates C++ as Object Oriented Language. The problem is when authors do so, the readers(mainly students) conveniently forget that C++ also fits for many types of programming languages.

Answer (score 6):

C++ contains a 'C' dialect as a subset, permitting a purely procedural style of code.

Answer (score 4):

The big arguments people have against declaring C++ as "pure" OO is that it still requires at least *one* non-OO bit, `main()`, and that not everything is an object (`int`, `long` et al).

It also exposes the state of an object for manipulation without using the message-passing paradigm (public members). This breaks the encapsulation of objects.

Java, on the other hand, has `main()` as just a static method of a class so it's closer but it still has non-object things in it.

Smalltalk is the lingua franca normally held up as the purest of the pure, but I don't know enough about it to comment.

Me, I tend to leave those sort of arguments for the intelligentsia while I get on with developing code and delivering to my clients :-)

Comment: Dont actually need main. Its just a well known entry point so command line and (some) GUIs no where to pass control to after load.

Answer (score 1):

Define OOL. If you mean using classes etc, then C++ supports OO-style of programming among others. There's nothing that stops you from not using classes. Java OTOH, does not allow for but classes. (Yes, I do know Java supports FP.)

Comment: "Yes, I do know Java supports FP.". That's new to me. Do you have any example of FP in Java?

Comment: A simple search gets me quite a few articles. One such: <http://www.ddj.com/java/184406320;jsessionid=NEAFYLK3RWELXQE1GHPCKH4ATMY32JVN?_requestid=113713>

Comment: dirk. I think you may mean Java supports **procedural** programming? Ne?

Comment: Without support for higher order functions, any "functional style" code in Java is going to be extremely convoluted. It may well be possible to emulate it, but such an endeavour could only be considered an intellectual exercise with little or no application in the real world.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is no - C++ is not entirely OO language.
You can write "not exactly" OOP using C++ even without resorting to using the C subset. One such example is your main method - which is not contained in any class.

The main reason is the fact that C++ originated from C - when Stroustrup created the language he was aiming to create a new version of C (with classes). in fact he have tried to submit his creation as the new flavor of C (C84).

Answer (score 0):

C++ is not a pure object oriented language, and as already mentioned nothing forces you to use OOP concepts in C++. C++ is what you call a hybrid object oriented language, as it's based on C which is purely a procedural language.

Examples of pure object oriented languages are C# and JAVA.

Comment: Neither of those are as primitive datatypes do not obey the same semantics as user defined datatypes.  Operations on them are not defined in terms of passing messages and they cannot be overloaded or redefined in a derived class.

Comment: No, Omni is saying that neither C# nor Java are pure OO since they have things like int and long which are *not* objects.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not a purely object oriented language.  In particular primitive datatypes in C++ have rules that are frequently different from datatypes that aren't primitive.  Additionally it is possible to have functions that are not associated with any datatype at all.  There are a myriad of other ways in which C++ is not a pure object oriented language, but those are two of the biggest reasons.

Neither Java nor C# are pure object oriented languages either because they have primitive datatypes that do not obey the same semantics as 'object' datatypes.

Answer (score 0):

of course not!!
It supports intrinsic data types.

Answer (score -2):

C++ is nothing but "C with classes". I can still write a C program and save it as .cpp file.
So, Proof by implication says "C++ is not a purely object oriented language."

Comment: C++ hasn't just been "C with classes" for a *very* long time :-)

Answer (score -3):

The reason why C++ is not a OOP language is mainly because it is missing the concept of encapsulation. You can't define an interface/contract to your object because of the pointers which give you total control on everything.