# Main Differences between c++ and Java

Tags: java, c++

What are the most important differences between C++ and Java from a point of view of someone coming from Java to C++?

Comment: Seriously? You'll learn, very quickly! ;)

Comment: I'm also new to C++, and also having a Java background, and there are so many differences that they are nearly incomparable.

Answer (score 5):

Too many to enumerate here but:

1. Garbage collection
2. Function pointers
3. Enumerators
4. The standard collection libraries (i.e. you're going to need to look up Boost for a hash table unless your compiler supports TR1)
5. Write once, compile many times for each operating system.
6. Multiple inheritance
7. Templates versus Generics and type erasure

Hell, pointers in general.  This question should be closed.  There's just no way to fully answer it.

Comment: have already answered you. I'll try to add some new differences

 1. 6 different type of inheritence |public, protected, private|*|virtual,nonvirtual|
 2. java is fully object-oriented, but c++ also structured, e.t.c

this is not full list. There are lot of differences, but here are the main ones.

Answer (score 1):

C++ is not completely object oriented where as java is. Also C++ compiles to machine language where as java compiles to byte code. you can find more here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_C%2B%2B

Comment: What do you mean by "not completey object oriented"? It's a multiparadigm language.

Comment: c++ lets you write procedural programs i.e most C programs are valid C++ programs. Also every C++ program will have main function which is not a member of any class. You can read this for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1635583/is-c-completely-object-oriented-languge

Comment: Java has primitives, so it isn't completely object oriented.

Comment: Any C++ compiler will allow you to write pure C programs. C is a structured language. In Java even for writing a mickey-mouse Hello world application you need to have a class.

Comment: @bin: How on earth is C a functional language? Do you mean imperative?

Comment: I meant procedural not functional. Editing my above comment.

Comment: C++ can be fully OO. It would be more reasonable to say that C++ in addition to being OO is also multi-pardiam. The way you phrase it suggests that C++ is lacking something that prevents if from being fully OO.

Comment: Forcing you to use objects does not mean that a language is fully object oriented, I've seen some very imperative Java code out there. At the same time, the fact that you can write imperatively does not mean that a language is not fully object oriented. Common Lisp for example is a multi-paradigm language and allows you to write functional and imperative code, yet still I would argue that because of the CLOS that it is **more** object oriented than Java.

Comment: I didnt mean any DISRESPECT to C++ but no C++ can not be fully object oriented. I am not saying that C++ has any weakness or any thing like that. I am simply pointing to fact that C++ has few things which are not objects like main() function is not part of any class and it has primitive types, which by the way Java also has.

Comment: Object-oriented is not "everything is a class". Object-oriented is not "everything is an object", either. The main method in Java is neither a class nor an object. Or any other method, for that matter. Does that make Java less object-oriented? No.